# Laravel, how to filter rows when using belongsToMany?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm confused about the Laravel API and its many to many relationship model.

There are the following tables:

`posts`
`tags`
`post_tag`

And I want to find posts which have `tagId = 123`

Is there simple source code similar to the following?

```
$posts= Post::find()->pivot->tag(123);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the method in Tag model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}
```

Then you can find posts which have `tagId = 123`

```
$posts = Tag::find(123)->posts();
```

Comment: It's my pleasure.